# Typing with enum field and a random string as key

Tags: typescript

I have an enum like this

```
export enum Test {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C'
}
```

I want a type that can have fields for each field of this enum A, B, C but also with the same fields concatenated with a string like 'A_2', 'B_2', 'C_2'

So for the A,B,C part I got this type

```
type TestExtended =  { [p in keyof typeof Test]: string }
```

How can I complete it to get 'A_2', 'B_2', 'C_2' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remap keys to be concatenated with `_2`:

```
type TestExtended =  { [P in keyof typeof Test as `${P}_2`]: string };
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like this (the `Partial` is optional):

```
type TestExtended = Partial<Record<`${keyof typeof Test}_2`, string>>;

const testExtended: TestExtended = { A_2: 'foo' };
```

Or even like this:

```
type TestExtended<T extends string = ''> = Partial<Record<`${keyof typeof Test}${T}`, string>>;

const testExtended: TestExtended<'_2'> = { A_2: 'bar' };
```